# how could I automatize the process that allows us to know if a job is finished or not?

Tags: salesforce, cloud, apex, asynchronous

On submission of an asynchronous job via the `Queueable` interface, a JobID is returned. This JobID can be used to programatically monitor the status of the asynchronous job via the `AsyncApexJob` table.
My Question is, how could I automatize this process to know when my job is finished?
The probleme is that we can not make a loop, that will wait until the job finish, by querying the `AsyncApexJob`..
How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can use few approaches for solving this problem: send a message on job finishing or create VF component for monitoring state of jobs. You can find code examples in answers for [this question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/17569/best-practices-for-monitoring-scheduled-apex-and-batch-apex).